# How to use a boolean in a while loop C++

Tags: c++

What is the correct syntax to use a while loop that exits when a boolean is true.

I'm not sure if this is works right:

```
while (CheckPalindrome(a, reverse) == false)
{
    CalcPalindrome(a, reverse);
    n = a;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        remainder = n % 10; //Finds the 1's digit of n
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        n /= 10;
    }
    CheckPalindrome(a, reverse);
}
```

Comment: You can shorten the condition to `while (!CheckPalindrome(a, reverse))` but why are you calling `CheckPalindrome(a, reverse);` a second time without checking the result at all?

Comment: I think it would be better, if you shared `CheckPalindrome` and `CalcPalindrome ` functions

Comment: Without knowing further about what your functions exactly do, I have a feeling you rather want a `do { ... } while (!CheckPalindrome(a, reverse));` loop. Or recursive calls of `CheckPalindrome(a, reverse)`.

Comment: You just negate boolean value using logical not operation, which is represented as  ! or `not` in C++

Comment: how do you check the result?

Comment: Do you want to break when the return value is true or when the value is false? You stated both in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to call `CheckPalindrome()` once, and that's in `while(CheckPalindrome())`

Also, the proper syntax is `while(!CheckPalindrome())`

So your optimized code would be:

```
while (!CheckPalindrome(a, reverse))
{
    n = a;

    while (n != 0)
    {
        remainder = n % 10; //Finds the 1's digit of n
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        n /= 10;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what that inner while loop is supposed to do, but that's the proper syntax for breaking from a `while` loop when a function returns `false`